# UITableView with fix position issue

Tags: xcode, ipad

I am using `UITableView` with custom cell with fixed y position to 118.
But when I run the application, tableview cell always set y to 0 position.
Why does it happen only in iPad?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Autolayout fixed]

Did you fix autosizing to false?

Comment: ok good. So share your answer, then it'll be helpful to others.